# NoSQL or MySQL?

Tags: database, database-design, mysql, nosql

I'm developing an app that requires to save data that is not consistent across all rows. These database entries represent different kind of sport activities. Let's take an example: In football the final result is an important field. However, in cycling there's no such field. So it wouldn't be a good idea to create a table that has a score column, would it? This kind of data would be easy to store in a NoSQL database.

All these have some things in common, though: date, time, duration and location, at least.

The app also has functionality that would greatly benefit from typical relational database. Users table, messages etc.

How should I implement a database for such an application? All data is relational in a way that connects everything to a specific user. However, not all data can be organized in a traditional row/column based database.

Should I use MySQL, and for these activities have a data field that contains the relevant data in JSON? What are my options?

Also keep in mind that the database might be holding millions of entries.

Comment: Why use the same database object to track un-alike data? Clearly, each sport has its own statistics and scoring, you would need different ways of storing it. Do not create an [inner-platform](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Inner-Platform_Effect).

Comment: @Snowman Creating hundreds of tables, one for each sport type wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: Then I think you just answered your own question.

Comment: @Snowman What if I used two databases? MySQL for all the relational data and then NoSQL (maybe MongoDB?) for the sports. I would have to do more queries, but I can't use joins in NoSQL either, so...

Comment: To paraphrase Mr. Myagi, either MySQL do or NoSQL do... but sit in the middle of road by using both... *squashed like grape*.

Comment: NotMySql, please.

Comment: IMHO you don't need a relational database at all.

Just stop thinking in a "relational" way.

I mean, you can have a "table" representing the users and the others documents that rely on user Id... start thinking by "document", people study RDBMS and think that is the only one solution, change the point of view.

Comment: @MiPnamic: Why should he think "document" when there is nothing described in the question which is remotely document-like?

Comment: @JacquesB There's a specific schema-less request up there. Anyway the truth is in the Middle and GrandmasterB just said that.

Answer (score 4):

It is no problem to have data "not consistent across all rows" in a relational database. This is precisely what relational databases are designed for! You create a table for the data which is common across all activities, and then you create separate tables for data specific for kind of activities. E.g. a football table with a score column, a cycling table with a distance column, both linked to the activities table with foreign keys.

So I'm skeptical that "not all data can be organized in a traditional row/column based database." You can always do that, unless you have very peculiar data. There are some cases where it might be *inconvenient* (eg. you have some complex application specific structured data which you never need to query or update - it might be easier to just serialize into a single field), but this depends on your particular use cases.

There is nothing in your question that indicates why a relational database wouldn't be fine.

Comment: I mostly agree with you. I often see people view rigid schema as something bad, while actually it can be very convenient tool. The only problem with this approach is when you need to change those sport-specific tables often (adding/removing new types of sort games). This is indeed the situation which might lead to invention of [inner-platform](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Inner-Platform_Effect) Snowman's mentioned. I've seen one of those, it is definitely the case when JSON/XML documents (not specifically NoSQL) might be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at PostgreSQL. [You can store JSON in it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) in a type-safe way. [It supports indexing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) so you can combine relational data with JSON documents pretty well. It is also fast, there are plenty of benchmarks.

Also, if you never used NoSQL before, please read this: [Why You Should Never Use MongoDB](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/) (don't mind the title, article is pretty constructive)

As for MySQL, I wouldn't suggest my worst enemy to use it. It has so much bugs it's not even funny. It pretty much doesn't work in a cluster (due to bugs some features become unusable and there are 1001 "workarounds" which make it unmaintainable), for one thing, so it's not a scalable solution.

So, choose between PostgreSQL and NoSQL at least. I definitely would recommend PostgreSQL.

**EDIT:**

I decided to mention some of MySQL bugs I happened to deal with to make it clear it is not just hate speech:

- [Incomplete XA support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xa-statements.html) (*"For XA START, the JOIN and RESUME clauses are not supported. For XA END the SUSPEND [FOR MIGRATE] clause is not supported."*) + [bug in official Java driver](http://bitronix-transaction-manager.10986.n7.nabble.com/After-deadlock-we-get-XAER-RMFAIL-exception-on-all-subsequent-db-access-Corrupted-connection-is-not--td1470.html) (this bug may be in MySQL itself, I'm not sure) causes (NUM_CORES*100)% CPU load on DB server, in which case you have to restart it.

  Workaround: **merging all databases which participate in distributed transactions into one** or **not using distributed transactions**. I participated in merging just 2 DBs, and that was brutal.
- [Deadlocks on concurrent inserts](http://thushw.blogspot.ru/2010/11/mysql-deadlocks-with-concurrent-inserts.html). Happens when you insert 4 values in 2 transactions, 2 each, in 2 [gaps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html) into some indexed field.

  Workaround: **serialization of inserts**. It means that practically you can only insert with one thread, hence no scalability for your application.
- Triggers and replication don't go together. There are few bugs, [like Bug #45677 related to AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-auto-increment.html)

  Workaround: **not using triggers** or **not using replication**. There are actually less brutal workarounds for each bug, but in the end of the day it's just what I said: choose either triggers or replication, not both.

Those are not even half of my list, but I want to emphasize that MySQL is bad when you need more than a single database with no replication. And it is especially important since scalability is one of the strongest arguments for using NoSQL solutions, and you mentioned you might have a lot of data.